# Finding leak - which pipe handles tub and sink drainage

Tags: plumbing

I have a leak inside my wall. It happens when water drains from the upstairs tub or sink. I don't think the toilet is involved because I don't smell any sewage.  What do you call the pipe that drains both the tub and sink but not the toilet?

Comment: Tubs, sinks, and toilets all have P-traps under them to stop smells from coming up the drains.  If the leak is between the sink/tub and p-trap should not get the smell but will get the leak/wetness.  They usually are connected to a larger drain pipe.

Comment: called simply a drain pipe,

Comment: Depending where you live and when the home was build, you might have separate drains for sewage and drain